# How to use AWS Cloudformation plugin from Intellij

Tags: amazon-web-services, plugins, intellij-idea

I am not sure which stackexchange group does this question belong to so starting from here.

I have downloaded AWS Clodformation  plugin for Intellij and want to learn how to create a cloudformation template using this plugin.  I have created a sample file which has default code like below.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Test the plugin
Resources:
  DummyServer:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      ImageId: ""
```

I want to learn AWS Cloudformation Template from scratch. I am hoping to be able to learn with the help of this plugin and was hoping it will give me suggestions for different attributes. I wasn't able to find how to use this plugin or even how to validate templates that others have given as a sample.

Is there any documentation for how to use this plugin to learn how to write the CF templates

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt Intellij's CloudFormation plugin is the way to move forward if you are new to CloudFormation and wants to learn from scratch.

Here are some pointers which might help you :)

- It's good to start coding in a code editor rather than an IDE if you are new and wants to learn. So I suggest *VSCode*
- Learn the CloudFormation basics. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/gettingstarted.templatebasics.html) AWS article contains a good starting guide
- Practice! Practice!! Practice!!!
- Once you get the basics right with CF, you can use VSCode plugins like `CloudFormation by aws-scripting-guy` or `CloudFormation Snippets by Danny Steenman` to help you code

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I will start with those.  The only reason I will not mark this as answer, so as not to make someone think that this is answer to use of the plugin

Comment: That's totally ok. I couldn't find any proper documentation for the plugin either. Happy learning!